# JavaScript isset() equivalent

Tags: javascript, isset

In PHP you can do `if(isset($array['foo'])) { ... }`. In JavaScript you often use `if(array.foo) { ... }` to do the same, but this is not exactly the same statement. The condition will also evaluate to false if `array.foo` does exists but is `false` or `0` (and probably other values as well).

What is the perfect equivalent of PHP's `isset` in JavaScript?

In a broader sense, a general, complete guide on JavaScript's handling of variables that don't exist, variables without a value, etc. would be convenient.

---

**Update**: 11 years and 11 months ago I posted this question, and wow, it still gets a lot of activity. Now, I'm pretty sure that when I wrote this, I only wanted to know how to check for the presence of a property in an associative array (a.k.a. dictionary), and as such the correct (for me) answers involve `hasOwnProperty` or the `in` operator. I wasn't interested in checking local or global variables.

But while I remember that well, that intent is not quite clear in the question as written, or even directly contradicted by it! I never mentioned the associative array, and PHP's `isset` does also do those other things. Let this be a lesson to all of us about how important it is to properly state your requirements in a question, and also how global variables, local variables, object properties, dictionary keys and what-have-you aren't Huey, Dewey, and Louie.

In the meantime (heh), many many people have provided answers to that effect as well, so for those of you who found this question through Google, well, I'm glad my vagueness helped in a way I guess. Anyway, just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: I wrote a function that will test the existence of an objects property no matter depth of query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12681101/1268003 Using my code, combined with some knowledge shared by @CMS in this thread, you can easily write a global function that works very much like PHP:s isset.

Comment: If you use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) try `_.isUndefined(arr.foo)`

Comment: Optional Chaining is probably what most people will be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845999/2100372

Comment: TLDR; For checking variables that might not have been declared, use `typeof v !== 'undefined'`. For checking variables that are known to have been declared, use `v !== undefined`. For objects, use `obj.property !== undefined` (regardless of whether or not the property has been declared).

Answer (score 1122, accepted):

I generally use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator:

```
if (typeof obj.foo !== 'undefined') {
  // your code here
}
```

It will return `"undefined"` either if the property doesn't exist or its value is `undefined`.

<sub>(See also: [Difference between `undefined` and not being defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420071/difference-between-undefined-and-not-being-defined-in-javascript/3420160#3420160))</sub>

There are other ways to figure out if a property exists on an object, like the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
  // your code here
}
```

And the `in` operator:

```
if ('foo' in obj) {
  // your code here
}
```

The difference between the last two is that the `hasOwnProperty` method will check if the property exist *physically* on the object (the property is not inherited).

The `in` operator will check on all the properties reachable up in the prototype chain, e.g.:

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar'};

obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // true
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false
'toString' in obj; // true
```

As you can see, `hasOwnProperty` returns `false` and the `in` operator returns `true` when checking the `toString` method, this method is defined up in the prototype chain, because `obj` inherits form `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Why use `typeof` rather than `if( obj.foo !== undefined )` ?

Comment: Ah. One day I will write a piece of truly cross-browser Javascript. Until then...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')`, not `obj.hasOwnProperty('bar')`?

Comment: the problem with this is that you get an error when you try to check deeper properties, for example: obj.thisdoesntexist.foo !== undefined. In PHP you can use isset or empty and safely at any deep.

Comment: IE8 doesn't has "hasOwnPropery"

Comment: Exactly, PHP allows `isset($abc->def->ghi->jkl)` without raising an exception and halting the script, unlike JavaScript's `typeof` operator. You have to use something like 
`try{ abc.def.ghi.jkl; isset=true }
catch(e){ isset=false }`

Comment: I have to extend my example to check for undefined properties: `try{ abc.def.ghi.jkl; isset=(typeof abc.def.ghi.jkl !== 'undefined') } catch(e){ isset=false }`

Comment: @StevenPribilinskiy while that solution is functionally fine it's not a neat function call and it's a significant performance issue (throwing an Error is really expensive). You might consider something like:  `isset(abc, "def", "hgi", jkl")` which can be implemented without a `try-catch`

Comment: @Halcyon a real-world comparison with jsperf would be much appreciated

Comment: http://jsperf.com/isset-trycatch-vs-loop It's a little bit more complicated. The `try-catch` method is severly asymmetrical. If it fails, it is 1000 (yes, one thousand) times slower. The loop method doesn't suffer from this asymmetry and performs well enough.

Comment: Wow, what a diversion, good to know. The `try-catch` block is 577x times slower when it fails and this indeed will not compensate the 8-16x advantage over loops when it succeeds. Thanks for preparing the test.

Comment: Since here we are talking about arrays, and since every array has a `length` property, wouldn't it be better to do so: `if (typeof arr.length != "undefined")` as a _general_ way to check if an array is empty/not-set or not?

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the same as PHP's `isset`, which returns `false` for variables explicitly set to `null`; whereas `typeof` returns `object` for variables set to `null`, as it does consider them defined. `typeof x != "undefined"` is more like using [`array_key_exists`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or [`property_exists`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).

Comment: @MattBall because "undefined" variable can be redefined with any value and it won't work then. 
var undefined = true;

Comment: @AlexeyKosov fortunately strict mode prevents assignment to `undefined`.

Comment: @MattBall, to leave things more clear, undefined without quotes to get it working.

Comment: Be careful when compare with str!
`typeof any !== 'unefined'` because of typo. **it happens.
to be sure use `typeof foo === typeof undefined`

Comment: @MattBall That's a good question, which should have been addressed in the answer (but cannot be because the edit queue is full). For an undeclared variable `v`, `v !== undefined` throws an error, but `typeof v !== 'undefined'` returns false.

Answer (score 83):

Age old thread, but there are new ways to run an equivalent `isset()`.

#### ESNext (Stage 4 December 2019)

Two new syntax allow us to vastly simplify the use of `isset()` functionality:

- [Optional Chaining(`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Nullish Coalescing Operator(`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator)

Please read the docs and mind the browser compatibility.

## Answer

See below for explanation. *Note I use StandardJS syntax*

### Example Usage

```
// IMPORTANT pass a function to our isset() that returns the value we're
// trying to test(ES6 arrow function)
isset(() => some) // false

// Defining objects
let some = { nested: { value: 'hello' } }

// More tests that never throw an error
isset(() => some) // true
isset(() => some.nested) // true
isset(() => some.nested.value) // true
isset(() => some.nested.deeper.value) // false

// Less compact but still viable except when trying to use `this` context
isset(function () { return some.nested.deeper.value }) // false
```

### Answer Function

```
/**
 * Checks to see if a value is set.
 *
 * @param   {Function} accessor Function that returns our value
 * @returns {Boolean}           Value is not undefined or null
 */
function isset (accessor) {
  try {
    // Note we're seeing if the returned value of our function is not
    // undefined or null
    return accessor() !== undefined && accessor() !== null
  } catch (e) {
    // And we're able to catch the Error it would normally throw for
    // referencing a property of undefined
    return false
  }
}
```

#### NPM Package

This answer function is available as the `isset-php` package on NPM. The package contains a few improvements such as type checking and supporting multiple arguments.

```
npm install --save isset-php
```

The full documentation is available in the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isset-php#readme).

```
const isset = require('isset-php')
let val = ''

// This will evaluate to true so the text will be printed.
if (isset(() => val)) {
  console.log('This val is set so I will print.')
}
```

---

## Explanation

### PHP

Note that in PHP you can reference any variable at any depth - even trying to
access a non-array as an array will return a simple `true` or `false`:

```
// Referencing an undeclared variable
isset($some); // false

$some = 'hello';

// Declared but has no depth(not an array)
isset($some); // true
isset($some['nested']); // false

$some = ['nested' => 'hello'];

// Declared as an array but not with the depth we're testing for
isset($some['nested']); // true
isset($some['nested']['deeper']); // false
```

### JavaScript

In JavaScript, we don't have that freedom; we'll always get an error if we do
the same because the engine is immediately attempting to access the value of `deeper` before we can wrap it in our `isset()` function so...

```
// Common pitfall answer(ES6 arrow function)
const isset = (ref) => typeof ref !== 'undefined'

// Same as above
function isset (ref) { return typeof ref !== 'undefined' }

// Referencing an undeclared variable will throw an error, so no luck here
isset(some) // Error: some is not defined

// Defining a simple object with no properties - so we aren't defining
// the property `nested`
let some = {}

// Simple checking if we have a declared variable
isset(some) // true

// Now trying to see if we have a top level property, still valid
isset(some.nested) // false

// But here is where things fall apart: trying to access a deep property
// of a complex object; it will throw an error
isset(some.nested.deeper) // Error: Cannot read property 'deeper' of undefined
//         ^^^^^^ undefined
```

More failing alternatives:

```
// Any way we attempt to access the `deeper` property of `nested` will
// throw an error
some.nested.deeper.hasOwnProperty('value') // Error
//   ^^^^^^ undefined

// Similar to the above but safe from objects overriding `hasOwnProperty`
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(some.nested.deeper, 'value') // Error
//                                        ^^^^^^ undefined

// Same goes for typeof
typeof some.nested.deeper !== 'undefined' // Error
//          ^^^^^^ undefined
```

And some working alternatives that can get redundant fast:

```
// Wrap everything in try...catch
try {
  if (isset(some.nested.deeper)) {
    // ...
  }
} catch (e) {}

try {
  if (some.nested.deeper !== undefined && some.nested.deeper !== null) {
    // ...
  }
} catch (e) {}

// Or by chaining all of the isset which can get long
isset(some) && isset(some.nested) && isset(some.nested.deeper) // false
//                        ^^^^^^ returns false so the next isset() is never run
```

## Conclusion

All of the other answers - though most are viable...

1. Assume you're only checking to see if the variable is not undefined which
   is fine for some use cases but can still throw an Error
2. Assume you're only trying to access a top level property, which again is
   fine for some use cases
3. Force you to use a less than ideal approach relative to PHP's `isset()`
   e.g. `isset(some, 'nested.deeper.value')`
4. Use `eval()` which works but I personally avoid

I think I covered a lot of it. There are some points I make in my answer that I
don't touch upon because they - although relevant - are not part of the
question(e.g. [short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)). If need be, though, I can update my answer with links to some of the
more technical aspects based on demand.

I spent waaay to much time on this so hopefully it helps people out.

Thank-you for reading!

Comment: Thank you. I use your option `isset()` all the time until now. Currently the optional chaining is very interesting. Instead of `if (isset(() => class.prop1.prop11)) {..}`, now I use `if (class.prop1?.prop11) {..}`. Not sure that it will work the same on every case and every details but just work for my case.

Answer (score 26):

> [Reference to SOURCE](http://locutus.io/php/var/isset/)

```
    module.exports = function isset () {
  //  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/isset/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)
  // improved by: FremyCompany
  // improved by: Onno Marsman (https://twitter.com/onnomarsman)
  // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
  //   example 1: isset( undefined, true)
  //   returns 1: false
  //   example 2: isset( 'Kevin van Zonneveld' )
  //   returns 2: true

  var a = arguments
  var l = a.length
  var i = 0
  var undef

  if (l === 0) {
    throw new Error('Empty isset')
  }

  while (i !== l) {
    if (a[i] === undef || a[i] === null) {
      return false
    }
    i++
  }

  return true
}
```

phpjs.org is mostly retired in favor of locutus
Here is the new link http://locutus.io/php/var/isset

Comment: This will raise an exception when calling `isset(abc.def.ghi)` in case if `abc.def` is undefined. However by combining this solution with the one that accepts a variable name in a form of a string, it will be identical to the PHP version.

Answer (score 23):

```
if (!('foo' in obj)) {
  // not set.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
//
//  tring to reference non-existing variable throws ReferenceError 
//  before test function is even executed
//
//  example, if you do:
//    
//     if ( isset( someVar ) ) 
//        doStuff( someVar );
//   
//  you get a ReferenceError ( if there is no someVar... ) 
//  and isset fn doesn't get executed.
//
//  if you pass variable name as string, ex. isset( 'novar' );, 
//  this might work:
//
function isset ( strVariableName ) { 

    try { 
        eval( strVariableName );
    } catch( err ) { 
        if ( err instanceof ReferenceError ) 
           return false;
    }

    return true;

 } 
//
//
```

Answer (score 9):

This simple solution works, but not for deep object check.

```
function isset(str) {
    return window[str] !== undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I always use this generic function to prevent errrors on primitive variables as well as arrays and objects.

```
isset = function(obj) {
  var i, max_i;
  if(obj === undefined) return false;
  for (i = 1, max_i = arguments.length; i < max_i; i++) {
    if (obj[arguments[i]] === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    obj = obj[arguments[i]];
  }
  return true;
};

console.log(isset(obj));                   // returns false
var obj = 'huhu';
console.log(isset(obj));                   // returns true
obj = {hallo:{hoi:'hoi'}};
console.log(isset(obj, 'niet'));           // returns false
console.log(isset(obj, 'hallo'));          // returns true
console.log(isset(obj, 'hallo', 'hallo')); // returns false
console.log(isset(obj, 'hallo', 'hoi'));   // returns true
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me.

```
function isset(object){
    return (typeof object !=='undefined');
}
```

Comment: Invoking `isset(var)` with `var` unset: `ReferenceError: var is not defined`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) I always use

```
if (!_.isUndefined(data) && !_.isNull(data)) {
     //your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty bulletproof solution for testing if a variable exists :

```
var setOrNot = typeof variable !== typeof undefined ? true : false;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot simply encapsulate it in a function.

You might think of doing something like this :

```
function isset(variable) {
    return typeof variable !== typeof undefined ? true : false;
}
```

However, this will produce a reference error if variable `variable` has not been defined, because you cannot pass along a non-existing variable to a function :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined

On the other hand, it does allow you to test whether function parameters are undefined :

```
var a = '5';

var test = function(x, y) {
    console.log(isset(x));
    console.log(isset(y));
};

test(a);

// OUTPUT :
// ------------
// TRUE
// FALSE
```

Even though no value for `y` is passed along to function `test`, our `isset` function works perfectly in this context, because `y` is known in function `test` as an `undefined` value.

Comment: Minor nit:  ` ? true : false` is superflous. The result of `!==` is already a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.isset = function(v_var) {
    if(typeof(v_var) == 'number'){ if(isNaN(v_var)){ return false; }}
    if(typeof(v_var) == 'undefined' || v_var === null){ return false;   } else { return true; }
};
```

plus Tests:

https://gist.github.com/daylik/24acc318b6abdcdd63b46607513ae073

Comment: As several earlier answers have mentioned, this will throw a ReferenceError if called with a variable that has never been declared.

Answer (score 4):

```
(typeof SOMETHING) !== 'undefined'
```

It's too long to write when used. But we can't package the `typeof` keyword into a function, because an error will thrown before the function is called, like this:

```
function isdef($var) {
    return (typeof $var) !== 'undefined';
}

isdef(SOMETHING); ///// thrown error: SOMETHING is not defined
```

So I figured out a way:

```
function isdef($type) {
    return $type !== 'undefined';
}

isdef(typeof SOMETHING);
```

It can work both with individual variables (variables that does not exist at all), or object properties (non-existent properties). And only 7 more characters than PHP `isset`.

Comment: This works for me, used it to check if a particular json response existed.

Answer (score 3):

```
function isset(variable) {
    try {
        return typeof eval(variable) !== 'undefined';
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: add some description too.

Comment: As several earlier answers have mentioned, this will throw a ReferenceError if called with a variable that has never been declared. E.g. `isset(someVar)`, where `someVar` has never been declared. However given that you do `eval`, you probably intend a *string* to be passed in. Show usage. Is your intended usage `isset('someVar')`?  If so, this looks similar to [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18358656/199364) - what about your answer is new?

Answer (score 3):

To check wether html block is existing or not, I'm using this code:

```
if (typeof($('selector').html()) != 'undefined') {
    // $('selector') is existing
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide the object path as a string, then you can break this string into a path and resolve `hasOwnProperty` at each step while overwriting the object itself with each iteration.

If you are coding in ES6 environment, take a look at [this stackoverflow Ques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990347/368691).

```js
var a;

a = {
    b: {
        c: 'e'
    }
};

function isset (obj, path) {
    var stone;

    path = path || '';

    if (path.indexOf('[') !== -1) {
        throw new Error('Unsupported object path notation.');
    }

    
    path = path.split('.');
    
    do {
        if (obj === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        stone = path.shift();
        
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(stone)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        obj = obj[stone];
        
    } while (path.length);

    return true;
}

console.log(
    isset(a, 'b') == true,
    isset(a, 'b.c') == true,
    isset(a, 'b.c.d') == false,
    isset(a, 'b.c.d.e') == false,
    isset(a, 'b.c.d.e.f') == false
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I use a function that can check variables and objects. very convenient to work with jQuery

```
    function _isset (variable) {
        if(typeof(variable) == "undefined" || variable == null)
            return false;
        else
            if(typeof(variable) == "object" && !variable.length) 
                return false;
            else
                return true;
    };
```

Comment: As several earlier answers have mentioned, this will throw a ReferenceError if called with a variable that has never been declared.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create function like empty function of PHP in Javascript.
May this helps.

```
function empty(str){
  try{
    if(typeof str==="string"){
        str=str.trim();
    }
    return !(str !== undefined && str !== "undefined" && str !== null && str!=="" && str!==0 && str!==false);
  }catch(ex){
    return true;
  }
 }

console.log(empty(0))//true
console.log(empty(null))//true
console.log(empty(" "))//true
console.log(empty(""))//true
console.log(empty(undefined))//true
console.log(empty("undefined"))//true

var tmp=1;
console.log(empty(tmp))//false

var tmp="Test";
console.log(empty(tmp))//false

var tmp=" Test ";
console.log(empty(tmp))//false

var tmp={a:1,b:false,c:0};
console.log(empty(tmp.a))//false
console.log(empty(tmp.b))//true
console.log(empty(tmp.c))//true
console.log(empty(tmp.c))//true
console.log(empty(tmp.c.d))//true
```

Answer (score 2):

finally i solved problem with easy solution :

```
if (obj && obj.foo && obj.foo='somethings'){
console.log('i,m work without error')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP Manual say:

> [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

And interface something like this:

`bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`

The parameter `$var` is the variable to be checked. it can have any number of parameter though.

isset() returns `TRUE` if var exists and has value other than `NULL`. `FALSE` otherwise.

Some example:

```
$foo = 'bar';
var_dump(isset($foo));        -> true

$baz = null;
var_dump(isset($baz));        -> false

var_dump(isset($undefined));  -> false
```

As this in mind, Apparently, It's not possible to write exact equivalent of php `isset()` function.
For example when we call like this:

```
if (isset(some_var)) {

}

function issset() {
    // function definition
}
```

Javascript trigger `Uncaught ReferenceError: some_var is not defined at (file_name):line_number`.
The important and remarkable thing about this behavior is that when trying to pass non-existent variables to normal functions, an error is triggered.

But in PHP `isset()` are not actually regular functions but language constructs. That means they're part of the PHP language itself, do not play by the normal rules of functions and can hence get away with not triggering an error for non-existent variables. This is important when trying to figure out whether a variable exists or not. But in javscript, it triggers an error in the first place say function call with non-existent variables.

My point is that we can't write it as equivlent javscript function but we can do something like this

```
if (typeof some_var !== 'undefined') {
   // your code here
}
```

If you want exact same effect PHP also check varable is not `NULL`

For example

```
$baz = null;
var_dump(isset($baz));        -> false
```

So, we can incorporate this into javascript then it look like this:

```
if (typeof some_var !== 'undefined' && some_var !== null) {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was really a problem for me when I was accessing a deeper property of an object so I made a function which will return the property value if exist otherwise it will return false. You may use it to save your time,

```
//Object on which we want to test
var foo = {
    bar: {
        bik: {
            baz: 'Hello world'
        }
    }
};


/*
USE: To get value from the object using it properties supplied (Deeper),
    if found it will return the property value if not found then will return false

You can use this function in two ways
WAY - 1:
Passing an object as parameter 1 and array of the properties as parameter 2
EG: getValueFromObject(foo, ['bar', 'bik', 'baz']);
WAY - 2: (This will work only if, your object available in window object)
Passing an STRING as parameter 1(Just similarly how we retrieve value form object using it's properties - difference is only the quote)
EG: getValueFromObject('foo.bar.bik.baz');
*/
function getValueFromObject(object, properties) {
    if(typeof(object) == 'string') {            //Here we extract our object and it's properties from the string
        properties = object.split('.');
        object = window[properties[0]];
        if(typeof(object) == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        properties.shift();
    }
    var property = properties[0];
    properties.shift();
    if(object != null && typeof(object[property]) != 'undefined') {
        if(typeof(object[property]) == 'object') {
            if(properties.length != 0) {
                return getValueFromObject(object[property], properties);    //Recursive call to the function
            } else {
                return object[property];
            }
        } else {
            return object[property];
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
console.log(getValueFromObject('fooo.bar.bik.baz'));        //false
console.log(getValueFromObject('foo.bar.bik.baz'));         //Hello world
console.log(getValueFromObject('foo'));                     //false
console.log(getValueFromObject('foo.bar.bik'));             //returns an object { baz: 'Hello World' }
console.log(getValueFromObject(foo, ['bar', 'bik']));       //returns an object { baz: 'Hello World' }
console.log(getValueFromObject(foo, ['bar', 'bik', 'baz']));//Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if an element exists, just use the following code:

```
if (object) {
  //if isset, return true
} else {
  //else return false
}
```

This is sample:

```js
function switchDiv() {
    if (document.querySelector("#divId")) {
        document.querySelector("#divId").remove();
    } else {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = "divId";
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", switchDiv);
```

```css
#divId {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn">Let's Diiiv!</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function for arrays or nested array (but not for strings)

```
if(isset(array,'key1=>key1')){alert('isset');}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dazzafact/cgav6psr/

```
arr={nested:{nested2:{val:'isset'}}}
if(t=isset(arr,'nested=>nested2=>val','=>')){
   alert(t)
}
function isset(obj,nested,split) {
var sep=split || '.';
    var dub=obj
    var isset=false
    if(typeof(obj)!="undefined" && typeof(nested)!="undefined"){
        var arr=nested.split(sep);
        for(var k in arr){
            var key=arr[k];
            if(typeof(dub[key])=="undefined"){
                isset=false;
                break;
            }
            dub=dub[key];
      isset=dub
        }   
    }
    
    return isset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful in ES6**, all the previous solutions doesn't work if you want to check a declaration of a **let variable** and declare it, if it isn't

example

```
let myTest = 'text';

if(typeof myTest === "undefined") {
    var myTest = 'new text'; // can't be a let because let declare in a scope
}
```

you will see a error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'myTest' has already been declared

The solution was to change it by a var

```
var myTest = 'text'; // I replace let by a var

if(typeof myTest === "undefined") {
    var myTest = 'new text';
}
```

another solution if you can change a let by a var, you need to remove your **var**

```
let myTest = 'text';

if(typeof myTest === "undefined") {
    myTest = 'new text'; // I remove the var declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  const value = array.foo.object.value;
  // isset true
} catch (err) {
  // isset false
}
```

Comment: I think this is actually a pretty simple and elegant solution to the need for an isset function, and bonus, it can detect infinite depth.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    isset('user.permissions.saveProject', args);

    function isset(string, context) {
        try {
            var arr = string.split('.');
            var checkObj = context || window;

            for (var i in arr) {
                if (checkObj[arr[i]] === undefined) return false;
                checkObj = checkObj[arr[i]];
            }

            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (var) {
  // This is the most concise equivalent of Php's isset().
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[javascript isset](https://gist.github.com/AlekseyArh/53811ecab8daa83a310215aa47eec1c2)

```
let test = {
  a: {
    b: [0, 1]
  }
};

console.log(test.isset('a.b'))   // true
console.log(test.isset('a.b.1')) // true
console.log(test.isset('a.b.5')) // false
console.log(test.isset('a.c'))   // false
console.log('abv'.isset('0'))    // true
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the most concise equivalent of Php's `isset()` :

```
if(var == undefined)
```

- `true`  this is var `!isset`
- `false` this is var `isset`

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways..