# Difference between undefined and not being defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

See http://jsfiddle.net/FDhQF/1/ for a trivial example.

What's the difference between something being undefined and something not being defined in Javascript? For instance, trying to access a property for an object (effectively, trying to access a variable) that isn't defined will return `undefined`. But you can also set something `= undefined`. When you do that, trying to access it still return undefined, but the pointer is still there. An example, as above, is how iterating over an object still goes over the property that you've (re)declared as undefined. It seems like there are two different sorts of undefined. Can anyone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: Please make sure that questions are self-contained and include all the relevant code directly, without linking to external sites.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Both, accessing a property that isn't defined on an object and a property that contains the primitive `undefined` value, will return you `undefined`.

For example:

```
var obj = {
  a: undefined
};

obj.a; // undefined
obj.b; // undefined
```

The difference is that `a` is an own property, and `b` isn't:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty('a'); // true
obj.hasOwnProperty('b'); // false
```

In the first case `a` is an own property, even if it contains `undefined` as its value. In the second case, `b` is not an own property, accessing `obj.b` will look for a property named `b`, all way up in the prototype chain.

When the prototype chain ends (when it reaches an object with a `null` `[[Prototype]]`), the property lookup ends and `undefined` is explicitly returned.

You should know that the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method checks only if the property physically exist on the object (*own* properties), but we have also *inherited* properties, for that case we can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator), for example:

```
function Test () {}
Test.prototype.a = 'foo'; // instances of Test will inherit from Test.prototype

var obj = new Test(); // { a="foo",  b="bar"}
obj.b = 'bar';

obj.hasOwnProperty('a');  // false
'a' in obj;               // true
obj.a;                    // 'foo'

obj.hasOwnProperty('b');  // true
```

As you can see, `obj` inherits from `Test.prototype`, and the `a` property is not an *own property*, but it is available through the prototype chain. That's why `hasOwnProperty` returns `false` and the `in` operator returns `true`.

You can see how internally properties are resolved by the [`[[Get]]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) internal operation

**Notes:**

- Accessing `undefined` as an identifier is not considered to be safe on ECMAScript 3 (the most widely implemented version of the language standard), because instead of being a language keyword (such as `null` for example) is just a property of the global object, and it is writable on this version of the Spec., meaning that if someone replaces its value (e.g. `window.undefined = 'LOL';`) , it will break your code.

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) as @strager mentions can be used instead, for example:

```
if (typeof obj.prop == 'undefined') { /*....*/ }
```

This operator returns always a string (it's safe to use `==` :), and its value depends of the type of its operand, the possible values are described [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3).

Another common way to solve this is to declare your own `undefined` variable, available on the scope of your functions, for example, some libraries use the following pattern:

```
(function(undefined) {
  // code here
})();
```

The function has an argument named `undefined`, and it is executed immediately without passing any value to it (the last pair or parens make the invocation).

Maybe is worth mentioning that the [`undefined` global property](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.1.1.3) was finally described on ECMAScript 5 as non-writable (immutable, as well non-enumerable and non-configurable -non deletable-).

- Using the `hasOwnProperty` method directly from an object instance is also not considered as *safe*, because if some object has a property with the same name, the original method will be shadowed. For example:

  ```
  var obj = { hasOwnProperty: function () { /* evil code :) */ } };
  ```

If you call:

```
    obj.hasOwnProperty('prop');
```

The method defined on the object will be executed (and you wouldn't want this since you know exactly which method you want to invoke...), because it *shadows* the one from the `Object.prototype`, however it can be safely invoked by:

```
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'prop');
```

Comment: In addition to `.hasOwnProperty`, there's also the `in` operator which, I think, needs mentioning.

Comment: On your first note: specify that, to check if a value is undefined, use `typeof x === 'undefined'`.  Also, I don't see why `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` would be considered unsafe; I use it for the same purpose for which you claim it is unsafe.  Can you clarify on this point?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, CMS. At this point, I still fail to see an advantage of Javascript's implementation of `undefined` over what seems to be the more conventional "throw/raise an exception" or "return `nil`/`null`" methodologies, but your answer definitely helps to shed light on the situation..

Comment: @Steven Xu, I myself wish there was an exception thrown on accessing an undefined property, but then again that prevents simple shorthands like `x = foo.bar || default;` which I just *love* in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.gibdon.com/2006/05/javascript-difference-between-null-and.html) is a good explanation of "undefined". The gist however is that setting something to "undefined" is not UN-defining it, because "undefined" is actually a primitive value, which is used when a variable (or property) has not been assigned a value.

Comment: `undefined` is actually a variable set to the primitive value initially.  The primitive value is used, not the variable, when returning from a function without an explicit return value, for example.

Comment: Also, the link you provided doesn't seem to answer the question directly.