# Using a javascript object like a java Map?

Tags: javascript

I need something of a HashMap in javascript. Can we do this:

```
var map = {};
map['foo'] = true;
map['zoo'] = true;
...

if (map['foo']) {
    // yes, foo exists.
}
else {
    // no, foo does not exist.
}
```

how do we properly check for the existence of the property without inserting it if it does not exist? For example, I don't want map.foo to exist after the above check if I didn't explicitly add it,

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, checking for:

```
if (map['foo']) {
  //..
}
```

Not only checks if the property is not defined on the object, the condition expression of the `if` statement will evaluate to `false` also if the property holds a value that coerces to `false` on boolean context (aka falsy values), such as `0`, `NaN`, an empty string, `null`, `undefined` and of course `false`, e.g.:

```
var map = {
  'foo': 0 // or any other falsy value
}; 

if (map['foo']) {
  // foo is truthy...
} else {
  // foo is falsy or not defined
}
```

To check if a *property exist* on an object, regardless its value -which can be *falsy*, even `undefined`- , you can use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method, for example:

```
var map = {};
map['foo'] = 0;

if (map.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
  // foo exist physically on the object...
}
```

The only problem with this method is that if someone adds a property named `hasOwnProperty` to an object, it wont work, for example:

```
var obj = {
    hasOwnProperty: 'bar'
};
```

If you execute `obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')`, it will give you a `TypeError`, because the object contains a string property that shadows the method -invoking the string would cause the error-.

A workaround to this is to call the `hasOwnProperty` method directly from the `Object.prototype` object, for example:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'prop')) {
  //..
}
```

You can also use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in):

```
if ('prop' in obj) {
  //...
}
```

The difference with the first method is that the `in` operator checks also for inherited properties, for example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false
'toString' in obj; // true, inherited from Object.prototype.toString
```

See also:

- [Difference between undefined and not being defined in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420071/difference-between-undefined-and-not-being-defined-in-javascript/3420160#3420160)

**Edit:**

Extending my response to the @slebetman comment, about checking `if (map.foo !== undefined)`.

As I was commenting, there are some concerns about accessing the `undefined` global property and also a *semantic difference* between checking a *property value* vs. *property existence*.

The `undefined` global property is not defined as read-only ECMAScript 3rd Edition Standard, (is now `writable = false` on ES5 :)

In almost all implementations its value can be replaced.

If someone makes:

```
window.undefined = 'foo';

// It will break your code:
var obj = {};
if (obj.foo !== undefined) {
  alert("This shouldn't ever happen!");
}
```

Also the semantic difference: by testing if `map.foo !== undefined` we are not technically only checking if the property exist on the object or not, a property can exist, holding undefined as a value, for example:

```
var map = {
  'foo': undefined
};

map.hasOwnProperty('foo'); // true, because the property exists although
                           //       it holds the undefined value
map.foo !== undefined;     // false
```

Comment: For empty objects created directly from the Object object (which is true in this case) using hasOwnProperty is not necessary. Just directly check if the value is undefined: `if (map.foo !== undefined)`.

Comment: @slebetman, yes but there are some concerns about accessing the `undefined` global property as an identifier, 1. Is not part of ECMAScript 3, (now is defined on ES5 :), 2. In some implementations the property is not read-only, its value can be replaced, e.g. if someone makes `window.undefined = true;`, it will break your code. Also checking `map.foo !== undefined` we are not technically checking if the property *exist* on the object or not, a property *can* exist, holding `undefined` as a value.

Comment: @slebetman — Also consider modifications to `Object.prototype`. Try this in your browser: `javascript:Object.prototype.foo=5;bar={};alert((bar.foo!==undefined)+","+bar.hasOwnProperty("foo"));Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty=function(){return true};alert(bar.hasOwnProperty("baz"))`

Comment: CMS: the `undefined` property of the global object **is** in ECMAScript 3. It's not specified as being read-only, so it can be replaced in all implementations I'm aware of. The change in ES5 is to make it read-only.

Comment: @Tim, yes sorry, -15.1.1.3- the only implementations where it is read-only at the moment, are the latest betas of Firefox 4, and the IE9 Platform Previews. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using [JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent/369009#369009)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
HashMap = function(){
  this._dict = {};
}
HashMap.prototype._shared = {id: 1};
HashMap.prototype.put = function put(key, value){
  if(typeof key == "object"){
    if(!key.hasOwnProperty._id){
      key.hasOwnProperty = function(key){
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, key);
      }
      key.hasOwnProperty._id = this._shared.id++;
    }
    this._dict[key.hasOwnProperty._id] = value;
  }else{
    this._dict[key] = value;
  }
  return this; // for chaining
}
HashMap.prototype.get = function get(key){
  if(typeof key == "object"){
    return this._dict[key.hasOwnProperty._id];
  }
  return this._dict[key];
}


var color = {}; // unique object instance
var shape = {}; // unique object instance
var map = new HashMap();
map.put(color, "blue");
map.put(shape, "round");
console.log("Item is", map.get(color), "and", map.get(shape));
</script>

<head>
<body>
<script>document.write("Existing Item Testing :\t\t\t" + map.get(color)+"
");
document.write("Non - Existing Item Testing :\t\t\t" + map.get("test")+ "");
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Existing Item Testing : blue
Non - Existing Item Testing : undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Map and Java HashMap are different things. Java Map is a hash table that has key labeled values, and a fast search of values by keys. HashMap on the other hand has the same seak time if you search value by key or key by value.

I wrote a similar data structure to Java Map, but I am still developing the HashMap class for javascript and I will share it as soon as I can. Note that my solution is just a wrapper to the native hash table, for easier use and iteration. A bit slower put and remove times, and a bit more of memory.

You can check it out on my blog, cause it is too long for here: http://stamat.wordpress.com/javascript-map-class/

Thanks for giving it a chance! Feedback is very appreciated! :)