# javascript reference to undefined property

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Using Firefox, working on a Firefox extension, I continually get a javascript warning:

```
reference to undefined property mySidebar.context.netProgress
```

I have tried multiple ways of testing the value:

```
if (mySidebar.context.netProgress === undefined) {
```

And

```
if (typeof mySidebar.context.netProgress == "undefined") {
```

And

```
if (!mySidebar.context.netProgress) {
```

And

```
if (mySidebar.context.netProgress == undefined) {
```

However the error console in Firefox continues to give me the warning on the same line every time, the line in question is the line that I posted the code from above. The actual check for the value is causing the warning.

I also put an alert to check the value of mySidebar.context, which is always an object, so it is not from the parent that I'm getting the warning.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could also just set it to `null` at browser startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try object.[hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if (mySidebar.context.hasOwnProperty("netProgress")) {
```

Comment: +1, I hope you don't mind me adding an example to your post.  Note that this won't work for properties inherited through the prototype chain.

Comment: Just note that `hasOwnProperty` checks for the *existence* of a property, the property could exist *and* its value could be `undefined`, see also: [Difference between undefined and not being defined in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420071/difference-between-undefined-and-not-being-defined-in-javascript/3420160#3420160)

Comment: Thanks CMS, this is fine as is, as I'm using this to check if the property exists before I try to add the property. WHen I remove the property, I use delete so it will work well for me.

Answer (score 6):

As Swingley said, you can use [*Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check for existence of a direct property on an object.  This won't work for properties inherited from the prototype chain, however.  For both situations, inherited and direct, you can use the [*in* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in):

```
if ("netProgress" in mySidebar.context) {
```

Comment: Isn't it too long? Using if (mySidebar.context.netProgress) is more AND MORE convenient…