# What does crockford mean when he says that undefined cannot be a property value?

Tags: javascript

In the book Javascript the good parts, on the opening page of Ch3 on objects, it states:

> An object is a container of properties, where a property has a name and a value. A property name can be any string, including the empty string. A property value can be any Javascript value except for undefined.

*Note*: *undefined* is highlighted in the book to denote that is is a literal.

In practice, however, I am able to do it.

```
var a = { "name": undefined };
```

What is wrong with my understanding ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is that he's wrong.

As you observe, you can set `var a = { "name": undefined };`.

- `a.name === undefined`
- `a.name === a.someFakeProperty`

Here's where they're different, though:

- `'someFakeProperty' in a === false`
- `'name' in a === true`

Or, to do it a different way,

- `a.hasOwnProperty('someFakeProperty') === false`
- `a.hasOwnProperty('name') === true`

Using the somewhat infamous `for..in` loop,

```
for (var i in a) {
    alert(i);
}
```

... will give you `name`.

So, by value you may not be able to distinguish undefined and `undefined`, but they are quite different internally.

<s>**Addition:** he's wrong about the property names, too - `a[window] = 43; a[window] == 43;` is just fine. Sure, you can't then do `a.window`, but `a.___` is just syntactic sugar for `a['___']`.</s> As noted in the comments, property names are cast to string so I was wrong about this bit.

Comment: He is not wrong about property names, when using the bracket notation, the expression will be converted ToString, property names can be *only strings*, e.g.: `var o = {toString: function () { return 'foo'; }}, a = {}; a[o] = 'test'; alert(a['foo']);` in this example, accessing `a[o]` will convert `o` to string, producing `'foo'` as property name...

Comment: Yep. Try `a['[object DOMWindow]'] == 43`.

Comment: Ah, I see... the string cast didn't occur to me. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the terminology that Crockford uses, he seem to mix the concept of `undefined` and *undeclared*.

The statement:

> A property value can be any Javascript value except for undefined.

Is completely wrong IMO, because [`undefined`](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x8.1) *is a* [**primitive value**](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x4.3.2) of the language.

See also:

- [Difference between undefined and not being defined in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420071/difference-between-undefined-and-not-being-defined-in-javascript/3420160#3420160)

Answer (score 2):

I think what he's trying to say is that a property's value cannot be `undefined` because `undefined` is exactly how JavaScript denotes properties that don't exist. In other words, if you have the following object

```
var a = { "name": undefined };
```

Then `a.name` is `undefined`, but so is `a.someFakeProperty`. However, as Ben Lee points out in his comment, `name` will still show up when you iterate the properties of `a` using a `for` loop, while `someFakeProperty` will not. Therefore, it seems that Crockford was a bit imprecise in conveying the idea in question here.

Comment: but there is a way to distinguish. If you do `a = { "name": undefined };` and then immediately follow up with `for (att in a) { alert(att); }`, you'll see `name` come up. So internally it is stored as a property of the object, with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: @Ben: Very interesting! I just tested that in Firefox, and it appears that you are right. Hmm, I wonder what Crockford was trying to say, then...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
var a = {"name": x}; //x is undefined, so it will cause an error.
```

Just my understanding.