# Is it okay to deliberately skip array elements using the comma operator?

Tags: javascript

```
var array = [,, "cat", "dog"];
```

This will create an array with two empty values (so that I can use them later on). I can't think of any other way to do this without doing the slow and tedious `array[2] = "cat"; array[3] = ...` Is this a good way to do this. Or is there another recommended practice that emulates this ability.

Comment: Why you need such array?

Comment: There was one time where I needed to put something into the front of a pre-filled array. I forgot what it was though but it brought up this question.

Comment: You could use then `array.unshift(value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The *holes* will not be defined, but contribute to the Array length.

[The spec <sup>*[ref]*</sup>](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.4) allows it:

> Array elements may be elided at the beginning, middle or end of the element list. Whenever a comma in the 
>   element list is not preceded by an  AssignmentExpression (i.e., a comma at the beginning or after another 
>   comma), the missing array element contributes to the length of the Array and increases the index of 
>   subsequent elements. Elided array elements are not defined.

However, as pointed by pimvdb, the fact that it's possible does not necessarily imply that it's a good practice.

Comment: The fact that it's possible does not necessarily imply that it's a good practice, IMO.

Comment: You could always add comments of some kind to clarify that the holes are intentional: `array=[ /* 0 */, /* 1 */, "cat", "dog" ]`

Comment: ...or just use an object, where you won't even need to incorporate bizarrely "blank" elements - just have the numeric keys you want mapped to values, and add new keys later when needed.

Comment: Note that as the spec. denotes, the elements will be *not defined*, which is a [bit different than being `undefined`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3420071#3420160), the corresponding numeric properties will not exist, e.g.: `'0' in [,]; // false` (With the exception of IE<=8, that has *several* bugs on the Array Initialiser syntax)

Answer (score 3):

The code at firsts looks like an error.

If you really want `undefined` values it would be beneficial to make it absolutely clear.

```
var array = [undefined,undefined, "cat", "dog"];
```

Not really better, but you could also do the following.

```
var array = ["cat", "dog"];
array.unshift(undefined,undefined);
```

It's definitely valid but not necessarily dry and clear.

Comment: `array.unshift(undefined,undefined)` would also work since you can pass multiple arguments, just like `.push()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's fine. Essentially what you're doing is declaring an array of four elements but without having to type in `undefined` for the first two. If, however, you *don't* want the length to equal four, you will have to do it another way.

It seems that your array is a list of elements where the mapping of the index to the value is important. If that is the case, you might consider using an object instead, which (I *think*) would be neater:

```
var obj = { 2: "foo", 3: "bar"};
alert(obj[2]);
// later
obj[4] = "baz";
alert(obj[4]);
```