# Check if parameter is present in JSON object at any depth

Tags: javascript, json, object, square-bracket

An API returns a JSON response at undefinable depth where some elements may or not be included. How do I check if a property is present? Some of the parameters include weird names like `@param` or `$`. Example for this follows.

I wrote a check for something similar, but cannot use the dot syntax for above reasons. Help for modifying this is highly appreciated.

```
function checkValue(objectPath) {
    var keys = Object.isArray(objectPath) ? objectPath : objectPath.split(".");
    if (keys[0] == "window") keys.shift();
    try {
    return keys.inject(window, function(obj, key) {return obj[key];});
    } catch (e) {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Example for the object to test on is:

```
var obj = {
member: {
    '@member-age': {
        value: 42
    }
}};
```

Before I checked it with `checkValue(obj.member.age)` but cannot do this for obvious reasons in this example.

Comment: Are you looking for a property *name*, or a property *value*?

Comment: for the property name, I need to check if it is present as otherwise the output will fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In javascript, test for property deeply nested in object graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343028/in-javascript-test-for-property-deeply-nested-in-object-graph) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+object+test+if+nested+property+exist)

Comment: did you want the value of that property? or just wether it exists?

Comment: @Patricia: I just need to check wether it exists.

Comment: @Felix: I was not able to find a solution for the naming problem in these. My problem are those names with unknown characters. Therefore I would like to call the function like checkValue(obj['@member-age'].value);

Comment: Most of the solutions there will work perfectly fine for `checkForProperty('obj.@member-age.value')`. You have to pass a string in any case.