# Javascript dot notation with variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Not sure how to word this.

I am trying to use a variable to determine how far to drill into an object to return a value.

```
var target = "level1.level2.var";
var myObject = {
                    level1: {
                        level2: {
                            var: 'value'
                        }  
                    }
               }
var returnVal = myObject.target;
```

How could this be done? Clearly this won't work. Is it possible some other way?

I figured I would have to maybe explode the target var and then loop for each level, but thought I'd ask to see if there was any easier way I could be overlooking.

Comment: `returnVal = eval("myObject."+target)` ?

Comment: @Shiplu: Yeah, but that uses `eval`.

Comment: As long as you are not passing user inputs there or check the string its safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In javascript how can I dynamically get a nested property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906108/in-javascript-how-can-i-dynamically-get-a-nested-property-of-an-object)

Comment: @Shiplu eval is also much slower than a simple split and loop

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Figured that was the only way. Hard to award since everyone answered pretty much the same. Just picking the one with the most votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function get_property_from_target(obj, target){
    var arr = target.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(obj)
            obj = obj[arr[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
get_property_from_target(myObject, target);
```

I'd rename the function to something better too.

Also please don't name an objects property `var` since that is a keyword in Javascript it can be confusing, and I'm not sure that it will always work the way you expect or if it will just cause errors in some browsers.

Comment: Added `if(obj)` into the loop so that it will return undefined if you send in an invalid target, instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

Easier? Sure, use `eval`:

```
var obj = eval('myObject.' + target);
```

That's not really a serious answer, though. You shouldn't use `eval` that way in good code. The only other way as far as I know, however, is to loop as you describe:

```
var items = target.split('.');
var obj = myObject;
var i;

for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[items[i]];
}
```

Or, with a regular expression hack:

```
var obj = myObject;
target.replace(/[^\.]+/g, function(m) {
    obj = obj[m];
});
```

Regardless, you can now use `obj`.

Comment: `/[^\.]+/g.exec('level1.level2.var');` returns `['level1']`.  Why not just use `target.split('.')`?

Comment: @Rocket: Yes, I was halfway into one solution :) I already edited it though, read again.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two ways of doing this:

- Using `eval()` (frowned upon, as `eval` is `evil`):

  ```
  var returnVal = eval('myObject.' + target);
  ```
- Using a loop:

  ```
  var split = target.split('.');
  var newTarget = myObject;

  for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      newTarget = newTarget[split[i]];
  }
  ```

Comment: I'd suggest not using `eval`, but I guess it's one solution.

Comment: I'll add in that it is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way, other than writing code to split your target on `.`, then for each token, drill down into the object as long as the "path" is valid.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do (maybe not the best, but it'll work), is what you've suggested.  Explode the variable, and then go to that level.

```
var target = "level1.level2.var";
target = target.split('.');

var returnVal = myObject;
for(var i=0,len=target.length; i<len; i++){
    returnVal = returnVal[target[i]];
}

console.log(returnVal); // value
```