# Obtain value from nested JSON dictionary via keypath without using eval

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I want to access a nested JSON dictionary via dynamically constructed keypath.
The keypath uses standard JSON dot and subscript operators.  (`.` and `[x]`)
E.g.:

```
var data = 
{"title": "a_title",
 "testList": [
   {
     "testListItemKey": "listitem1"
   },
   {
     "testListItemKey": "listitem2",
          "deepTestList": [
            {
              "testListItemKey": "listitem1",
                      "testListItemDict":{
                         "subTitle": "sub_title",
                      }
            }]
   }]
}
```

An example keypath string would be:

```
data.feedEntries[0].testList[2].deepTestList[1].testListItemDict.subTitle
```

The simplest working solution I found so far is to use eval or function constructors:

```
function valueForKeypPath(data, keyPath) {
    "use strict";
    var evaluateKeypath = new Function('data', 'return data.' + keyPath);
    return evaluateKeypath(data);
}
```

As I can't fully trust the JSON data I receive from a remote endpoint, I'd like to avoid eval et.al.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In javascript how can I dynamically get a nested property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906108/in-javascript-how-can-i-dynamically-get-a-nested-property-of-an-object)

Comment: This has been asked a number of times ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all `"["` to `"."` and `"]"` to `""` so you get to

```
feedEntries.0.testList.2.deepTestList.1.testListItemDict.subTitle
```

Split this into a path array like using path.`split('.')`

```
var paths =  ['feedEntries','0','testList','2']
```

then just

```
var root = data;
paths.forEach(function(path) {
   root = root[path];
});
```

at the end root contains the desired data fragment.

Answer (score 0):

What if you are using "underscore", I recommend [underscore-keypath](https://github.com/jeeeyul/underscore-keypath)