# angular How to access dynamic multiple level data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data that I would like to loop through with ngRepeat and access data dynamically that's either on the top level or nested under a couple of levels.

However, it seems like I can get the top level properties to show up, but not when its nested.

JS:

```
var mapping = [
    {property:'a'}, // works
    {property:'b.c1'}, // doesn't work
    {property:'b.c2'}  // doesnt work
];

var arr = {
    a: 'text',
    b: {
        c1: 'text2',
        c2: 'text3'
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="mappingItem in mapping">
    <p>{{arr[mappingItem.property]}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: did u try this? var mapping = [
    {property:'a'}, 
    {property:'b['c1']'}, 
    {property:'b.['c2']'} 
];

Comment: @DivyaMV just tried and does not work

Comment: if you use arr['b.c1'] it wont work but if you use arr['b'].c1 then it works

Comment: This might help if changing the structure is not an option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906108/in-javascript-how-can-i-dynamically-get-a-nested-property-of-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular's [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service to evaluate the expression against `arr`:

```
$scope.map = function(property) {
    return $parse(property)(arr);
};

<div ng-repeat="mappingItem in mapping">
    <p>{{map(mappingItem.property)}}</p>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tPYcyT4HhqaepJZl0kd8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your approach will work. Reason being the way you are trying to access the object is incorrect, i.e.: `arr[mappingItem.property]` will become `arr['b.c1']` but your object doesn't have a key `'b.c1'`. @DivyaMV's suggestion won't work either because property `b` in the `mapping` isn't an object hence it doesn't have a key `c1`. I'd suggest you either change the structure of your object **OR** you change how you are trying to access your object i.e. use `ng-if` to check for multiple levels, **OR** instead of looping, display the properties one by one

Answer (score 0):

If you use  {"property":"b","chiled":"c1"} type of structure then it works.

```
var mapping = [
    {property:'a'}, 
    {"property":"b","chiled":"c1"},// works
    {property:'b.c2'}  
];
```

```
 <div ng-repeat="mappingItem in mapping">
    <p>{{arr[mappingItem.property][mappingItem.chiled]}}</p> <!-- it works for second object-->
 </div>
```

Comment: Won't this return `undefined` for first object?

Comment: yes i actually given example for nested  json iteration so only second object work its just an simple example to iteration nested json so its on you to decided how i construct your json