# php isset() equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the javascript equivalent of the php function `isset()`. I've tried the method described here at [JavaScript isset() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent) but at firebug, error comes up saying

```
data.del is undefined                          //Firebug warning/error
 if(typeof data.del[0].node != 'undefined') { // codes in my js file
```

And in some cases

```
data is null                                  //Firebug warning/error
  if(typeof data.storyLine != 'undefined') { // codes in my js file
```

The logic seems to work but I'm wondering why is there an error then??

Basically, I want to check whether `data.del[0].node` or `data.storyLine` isset or not??

Comment: or you can use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: please elaborate on what conditions will return a result of `true` for `isset()`, specifically: `NaN` and `undefined`

Comment: @zzzzBov, it's jst i make a msql query, if data are there, i return them, using json_encode of an array.. if data are not there, nothing is returned.

Comment: then use `data.hasOwnProperty('foo');`

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I distinctly remember watching a [lecture given by Douglas Crockford](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) mentioning something about an issue with `in` but I believe it was in the context of a `for...in` loop. I believe `in` will work in most cases, but i'm more certain `hasOwnProperty` will work as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript isset() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent)

Comment: Refer this for answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent/56887380#answer-56887380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECMAScript defines the `hasOwnProperty` method for checking if an object has a property of a given name:

```
var foo = {'bar':'bar'}

alert( foo.hasOwnProperty( 'bar' ) ); //true
alert( foo.hasOwnProperty( 'baz' ) ); //false
```

EDIT: This doesn't fully answer your question

It's possible for a property to be set as `undefined`

```
foo.bar = undefined;

alert( foo.hasOwnProperty( 'bar' ) ); //still true
```

The important question is: What do you need your truth table to be?

In php:

```
type  | isset() | == true
------+---------+----------
null  | false   | false
false | true    | false
true  | true    | true
""    | true    | false
"a"   | true    | true
0     | true    | false
1     | true    | true
```

In JS:

```
type      | isset() | truthy
----------+---------+--------
NaN       | ?       | false
undefined | ?       | false
null      | false   | false
true      | true    | true
false     | true    | false
""        | true    | false
"a"       | true    | true
0         | true    | false
1         | true    | true
```

Comment: it's jst that, after making a mysql_query, if the data im seeking is in the database, im returning the data using json_encode() function of PHP. If the data is not there in the database, it's never returned. So I want to checked whether data did arrive from the database. If i got the data.. i do stuffs.. if i don't dont do stuffs.. that's like it.

Comment: it works... i've tried `if(typeof data.node != 'undefined')`, `if(data.node != 'undefined' && data.node != 'null')`, and `data.hasProperty('node')`.. all of them seems to work.. but all of them throws up this red error in firebug so i'm just worried and wondering if it's working by luck!!

Comment: @zzzzBov - Oops, sorry, I moved the comment because I didn't know if you'd see it. Here's a test that I wasn't confident enough to post as an answer, which uses `in`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRnda/ Note: No Firebugz errors! (FF 4, FB 1.7)

Comment: @ptamzz, i assume you forgot the `typeof` in your second example. They're all valid ways of checking if a property was set, the only difference between them will be the edge cases.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, `in` is a valid operation in JS, it won't throw an error, it just might behave unexpectedly in certain edge cases.

Answer (score 11):

isset() makes [two checks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): first if the variable is defined, and second if it is null.

You will have to check for both the 'undefined' case and the null case, for example:

```
if (typeof data !== 'undefined' && data !== null)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to look in the source code of [php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/isset:454):

```
function isset () {
    // !No description available for isset. @php.js developers: Please update the function summary text file.
    // 
    // version: 1103.1210
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/isset
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: FremyCompany
    // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Rafał Kukawski
    // *     example 1: isset( undefined, true);
    // *     returns 1: false
    // *     example 2: isset( 'Kevin van Zonneveld' );
    // *     returns 2: true
    var a = arguments,
        l = a.length,
        i = 0,
        undef;

    if (l === 0) {
        throw new Error('Empty isset');
    }

    while (i !== l) {
        if (a[i] === undef || a[i] === null) {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```