# Test if a variable is defined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How should I test if a variable is defined?

```
if //variable is defined
    //do this
else
    //do this
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') {
  // ..
}
else
{
     // ..
}
```

find more explanation here:

[JavaScript isset() equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent)

Comment: Use !== for strict comparison and better performance.

Comment: @AmericanYak—in a *typeof* test the algorithm for resolving [`==`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and [`===`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) is identical since both values have the same Type (string), so where does the better performance come from?

Comment: This fails when because `typeof null` is `Object`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `in` operator.

```
'myVar' in window; // for global variables only
```

`typeof` checks will return true for a variable if,

1. it hasn't been defined
2. it has been defined and has the value `undefined`, or
3. it has been defined but not initialized yet.

The following examples will illustrate the second and third point.

```
// defined, but not initialized
var myVar;
typeof myVar; // undefined

// defined, and initialized to undefined
var myVar = undefined;
typeof myVar; // undefined
```

Comment: You can use *in window* only in the special case of global variables as they are also made properties of the global object. Local variables have no such accssible variable object. Assuming that there is a window object might be reasonable for browsers but is not neccessarily true in general.

Comment: @RobG - it doesn't have to be `window` or the global object. Any object can be used here instead. You've raised a good point about variables defined locally not being accessible here. I'll be interested in finding out if there's a way to determine undefinedness for local variables based only on the first criteria I have.

Comment: If you are talking about variables and scope, then you can only distinguish between global variables (as they are properties of the global object) and the rest. In a nested function, it is impossible to tell if an identifier is a local or outer function variable because you can't access the related variable objects. Object property resolution is a different thing.

Comment: @RobG it's still the best answer because testing if the variable is merely equal to undefined doesn't mean anything other than it's undefined... but the variable might exists.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix—there are no good answers here, it is impossible to tell if a local variable "exists" or not.

Answer (score 4):

You simply check the type.

```
if(typeof yourVar !== "undefined"){
  alert("defined");
}
else{
  alert("undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
if (typeof varname !== 'undefined') {
    // do this
} else {   
    // do that
}
```