# What is the best way to check if a variable is set?

Tags: javascript

In my opinion Javascript has quite a few weird quirks. Here is one of them

```
var a;
!a //true, a is not set
a = null
!a //true, a is not set
a = 1
!a //false, a is set!
a = 0
!a//true, a is not set!
```

All of these values i find to be quite reasonable, except for the case where a = 0, this is just plain wrong to me. Is there any reasonable way of circumventing this issue without having to add to bulk to my code?

Comment: [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) ?

Answer (score 1):

check it using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FSpecial_Operators%2Ftypeof)

```
if(typeof(a) != "undefined") {
     //code goes here
}
```

Here are some related questions.

[How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

[Test if a variable is defined in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578917/test-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript/7578941#7578941)

Comment: As `typeof` is an operator and not a function, you don't need the brackets actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof a !="undefined")
{
 //write your code here
}
```