# Javascript isset function

Tags: javascript, isset

I created an *isset* function to check if a variable is defined and not null.
Here's my code:

```
isset = function(a) {
    if ((typeof (a) === 'undefined') || (a === null))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
};
var a = [];

// Test 1
alert(isset(a['not']); // Alerts FALSE -> works OK
// Test 2
alert(isset(a['not']['existent'])); // Error: Cannot read property 'existent' of undefined
```

Any suggestion to make my function work for test 2?
Thanks.

Comment: `typeof` is an operator not a function, you should get rid of the `()` around the values you are testing with it.

Comment: @Quentin: it's arguable, some prefer to use parenthesis for all control statements to make the code more consistent and readable. For instance, some prefer to write `return (true)` instead of `return true`. It's a matter of preferences (and irrelevant to the question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript isset() equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to check property of an undefined object. It doesn't make any sense. You could write like this:

```
alert(isset(a['not']) && isset(a['not']['existent']));
```

Comment: You are right. I just was wondering if it is possible to create a php like isset function. 
In php you can do this: var_dump(isset($a['not']['exists'])); 
Thanks for response!

Answer (score 3):

that won't work, and you can't make it work.
what happens is this:
the js engine tries to evaluate a['not'] and get's "undefined", then it tries to evaluate the property 'existent' of the undefined and you get that error.
all of that happens **before** the call to your function...

what you can do is something like:

```
var isset = function(obj, props) {
    if ((typeof (obj) === 'undefined') || (obj === null))
        return false;
    else if (props && props.length > 0)
        return isset(obj[props.shift()], props);
    else
        return true;
};
```

then you call it like this:

```
var a = [];

// Test 1
alert(isset(a, ['not']);
// Test 2
alert(isset(a, ['not', 'existent']));
```

(**this just a pseudo code, you might need to modify it a bit to actually work)

Answer (score 1):

Test 2 will not work because "a['not']['existent']" value resolution precedes "isset" function call, and results in a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can do right this:

1) as we do in php:

```
$vara = "abc";
$a =0;

 while(isset($vara[a]){
a++;
}
```

---

2) as I do in javascript:

```
vara = "abc";
 while (vara[a] != null){
a++;
}
```