# How do I traverse a JavaScript object and check for nulls?

Tags: javascript, isnull

Let's say I have a JavaScript object like:

```
var obj = {};
obj.computers = {};
obj.computers.favorite = "Commodore 64";
obj.computers.popular = "Apple";
```

Now, I can easily check for null like:

```
if(obj != 'undefined' && obj != null) {
    if(obj.computers != 'undefined' && obj.computers != null)) {
        .....
```

As you can see, if I need to see if `obj.computers.favorite` has been set, I have to really nest some conditional logic there.  Some of our objects go 3, 4, 5 levels deep.

This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
var fav = obj.computers.favorite || 'Unknown';
```

But I realize I would need to wrap that in some method.  Something like:

```
var fav = getValueOrDefault(obj.computers.favorite, 'Unknown');
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

My checking for 'undefined' isn't actually what I use.  It just came out of my head when asking the question.  lol

But I was wondering, could I just wrap in a try/catch and throw default if exception?

```
function(obj, default) {
    try {
        if(obj != null) {
            return obj;
        } else {
            return default;
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Also, thanks to Shusi for pointing the redundant vars.

Comment: `obj != 'undefined' && obj != null` is incorrect, since to get a string value `'undefined'`, you'll need typeof. This is a common bug. But either way, it is needlessly verbose. Just do `obj != null`, and it will test for `undefined` at the same time.

Comment: `getValueOrDefault(obj.computers.favorite, 'Unknown')` would throw an exception if `obj.computers` were undefined. You'd have to wrap it in a string and do incremental object parsing.

Comment: @saml exactly.  Which is what I'm trying to avoid.  Our JS objects go really deep sometimes.  I guess I could just do a try/catch and return default if exception?

Comment: Optional Chaining is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845999/2100372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a *helper* function. If I understand your problem correctly, your objects **may have** arbitrary deep objects, and you want to access these arbitrary nested properties without cluttering your code. I built a `Nested` function which lets you `get()` arbitrary properties if they are set, or a default if they are not.

```
var Nested = function() {};
// prop is a dot-separated path like "foo.bar.baz"
Nested.prototype.get = function(prop, _default) {
    var current = this;
    $.each(prop.split("."), function(i, e) {
        current = current[e] || undefined;
        if (current == undefined)
            return false;
    });
    return current || _default;
}
```

You can then write code like this

```
var fav = obj.get("computers.favourite", "Linux");
// this emulates
var fav = obj.computers.favourite || "Linux"; // throws error
```

As you can see, it's not so much more typing. Sure, it doesn't feel like *regular Javascript*... [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwSbu/1/).

Comment: err, you need to change the var declaration to `var current = this;` and in the code `current = current[e] || undefined;`. the fiddle then will work correctly.

Comment: you should mention your answer requires jquery.

Answer (score 6):

You can really write:

```
(obj && obj.computers && obj.computers.favorite) || 'Unknown'
```

Comment: +1, but see my answer to a general solution which doesn't clutter the code with many `and`s and is more useful if OP uses this pattern more than once.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this to help you deal with one of your questions: "*I need to see if obj.computers.favorite has been set*".

```
Object.prototype.isset = function (/* string */ full_path)
{
    var props = full_path.split('.');
    var self = this; /* note that self is usually the window object */

    for (var ii = 0; ii < props.length; ++ii)
    {
        var prop = props[ii];
        var hasMoreComing = ii < props.length - 1 ? true : false;

        if (self[prop] !== null && typeof self[prop] === 'object' && hasMoreComing)
        {
            self = self[prop];
            continue;   // Move up one level.
        }
        else if (hasMoreComing)
            return false;    // ..because user queries a subproperty of a value type

        return self.hasOwnProperty(prop);
    }
};
```

**Test-code:**

```
var test = {};

test.kuk = {};
console.log( test.isset('kuk') );  // Prints true.

test.kuk.fitta = {};
console.log( test.isset('kuk.fitta') ); // Prints true.

test.kuk.fitta = null;
console.log( test.isset('kuk.fitta') ); // Prints true.

test.kuk.fitta = undefined;
console.log( test.isset('kuk.fitta') );  // Prints true

delete test.kuk.fitta;
console.log( test.isset('kuk.fitta') );  // Prints false

test.kuk.fitta = 123;
console.log( test.isset('kuk.fitta.doesnt.exist') );  // Prints false
```

Comment: This doesn't work like PHP isset as it returns true for null and undefined.

Answer (score 1):

following  function will take string as parameter and return object if exist

```
 function getValueOrDefault(str , obj, deflt){
    var a = str.split("."); o = obj;
    for(var i =0; i < a.length; i++){
         o = obj[a[i]];
         if(!o){
           return deflt;
         }
    }
      return o;
}

var obj = {};
obj.computers = {};
obj.computers.favorite = "Commodore 64";
obj.computers.popular = "Apple";
getValueOrDefault('computers.favorite', obj, 'Unknown');
```

Note: You must not use var while assigning properties  to object eg. `var  obj.computers.favorite`  is SYNTAX error.

Comment: I think you could swap `obj` and `deflt` params and change the `o = obj || window`.
so you could write `getValueOrDefault('obj.computers.favorite', 'unknown')`

Comment: Yes, you are right. but this solution was more specific to above question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a super easy way to get around this, but you don't need to check for both null and undefined.  Because null and undefined are both falsey, you can just do:

```
if (obj && obj.computers) {
  var fav = obj.computers.favorite || 'unknown';
}
```

It doesn't actually get around what your complaint is, but it's less painful than what you'd think.

Answer (score 1):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is a more recent way to handle this:

```
let favorite = obj?.computers?.favorite;
```

Combining this with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), you can do precisely what was originally requested:

```
let favorite = obj?.computers?.favorite ?? 'Unknown';
```

Note that neither of these operators is universally supported yet though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with *JavaScript ES5* `reduce` function :

```
function get(root, member) {
    return member.split('.').reduce((acc, value) => {
        return (acc && typeof acc[value] !== 'undefined') ? acc[value] : undefined
    }, root);
}
```

It makes a array out of the member string, then the accumulator progressively traverse within the object as the members are reduced.

You can use it like this, even with arrays :

```
let obj = {
    computers : {
        favorite : "Commodore 64",
        popular : "Apple",
        list: [
            {
                sn : "TDGE52343FD76",
                price: "9867.99",
                options: {
                    fanless: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

get(obj, 'computers.popular');
// => "Apple"
get(obj, 'computers.list.0.sn');
// => "TDGE52343FD76"
get(obj, 'computers.list.0.options.fanless');
// => true
get(obj, 'computers.list.0.options.runsWithoutEletricity');
// => undefined
get(obj, 'computers.list.0.options.runsWithoutEletricity') || "too bad..." ;
// => "too bad..."
```

There is a codepen to [safely traverse js object](https://codepen.io/gabriel-glenn/pen/NZXrBV)