# How to check if isset is not set?

Tags: javascript, php, html, request, isset

I am using this line of code to check if isset is not set.

for example :

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['search']))
{ }
else if(!isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{}
```

I just want to know if !isset is a valid code. If not, what is the proper method? Thanks

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `!isset`. `else ifif` On the otherside isn't.

Comment: @Anant Why exactly is it a "much better approach" ?, If you just want to check if something isn't set, then why write the whole `if else` construct and not just use `!isset`?

Comment: @Daan forgive my typo on "ifif"

Comment: @Anant You're dodging the question. Why write the whole `if else` construct if you just want to check if something isn't set? "! is not a better thing" is just wrong.

Comment: @Anant what if i wanted to write like this if(!isset($_REQUEST['search']))
{ }
else if(!isset($_REQUEST['sumbit']))
{ }

Comment: @Anant all i wanted to know if !isset() valid from SO users

Comment: @Anant thanks a lot Anant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd fine to use `!isset`, no issue, but `else ifif` is completly wrong in your code

Approach will be:-

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){  // check that variable is set and have some value or not
    // variable is set and have value
}else {
   // variable is either not set or not have  value
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you.:)):):

Answer (score 1):

**Checking a variable is set**

To make it work, you pass a variable in as the only parameter to isset(), and it will return true or false depending on whether the variable is set. For example:

```
<?php
    $foo = 1;
    if (isset($foo)) {
        echo "Foo is set\n";
    } else {
        echo "Foo is not set\n";
    }
    if (isset($bar)) {
        echo "Bar is set\n";
    } else {
        echo "Bar is not set\n";
    }
?>
```

That will output "Foo is set" and "Bar is not set". Usually if you try to access a variable that isn't set, like $bar above, PHP will issue a warning that you are trying to use an unknown variable. This does not happen with isset(), which makes it a safe function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here You are sending userName from post method.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['userName']))
    {
    //your code 
    header("location: dashoard.php");
    }
    else{
    // your code
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    ?>
```