# How to master this conditional promise in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I must solve a problem in `angularjs` and I'm stuck for some hours right now.

if have this pseudo code:

```
doSomething(param){

    var res;
    if(param = "ok"){
        //do some api calls with promise
        res = promise result
     }

    doSomeStuff(){
        //if i got res variable, continue with this...
        // else
        //if res is not set, do this...
    }
```

So my question is: How i can do something like this?
The `doSomeStuff` function needs to know, if variable `res` is set or not. So it needs to wait, or to continue, if the variable `res` is not set.

Comment: Put the `doSomeStuff` code in the `then` of your promise. Remove the `res` variable and the promise itself should return a set/unset value, which you can use to branch within `doSomeStuff`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript isset() equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281633/javascript-isset-equivalent)

Comment: @darham hardly a duplicate of that question. This question involves asynchrony as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one api call : use the `then()` of the $http

```
doSomething(param){
    if(param == "ok"){
        //do some api calls with promise
        $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: url
        }).then(
           function success(response) {
                doSomeStuff(response);
           },
           function error(response) {
              console.log(response);
           }
        );
    }      
}
```

If you need to make many APi calls :

```
var doSomething = function (param){
    if(param == "ok"){
       // imagine that listeUrl is an array of url for api calls   
       var promises = [];
       for (var i in listeUrl ) {

          promises.push( //Push the promises into an array
              $http({
                 method: 'GET',
                 url: listeUrl[i]
              }).then(function success(response) {
                 return response.data;
              })
          );
       }
       return $q.all(promises); // Resolve all promises before going to the next .then
    }      
}

doSomething("ok").then(function(res){
    doSomeStuff(res);
});
```

Comment: note that `if(param = "ok")` is not a comparison but an assignment

Comment: thank you for your answers... but.. in the " doSomeStuff() " there is an " if/else " depends on the " res "  variable.. so the solution from @AlainIb is not really what i need... or do i understand it wrong?

Comment: you barely didn't provide anything to help us ... i edit the answers, just pass the response to your function, and inside it test the value like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'then'  from angular so that once promise is resolved you can check the data returned from promise and perform your logic