# how to use correctly [ngStyle] with function

Tags: angular, background-image

I have the following error that constantly returns me the debug console

> HomeComponent.html:33 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
>       at HomeComponent.getImageEvent (home.component.ts:73)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:33)

**HomeComponent.html**

```
<div [ngStyle]="getImageEvent(i)">
```

**home.component.ts**

```
getImageEvent(index: number): object {
 return {'background-image': 'url(' + this.events[index].images[0].url + ')'};
}
```

Comment: The issue might be inside your array. Any chances your `images[0]` not have the `url` property? Or the images array be empty? try `console.log(this.events[index].images)` and see what shows up

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you gave me, do not really consider that bug, sometimes you do not see the essentials !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see:

> Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

It means something is undefined. Which means, the object you are trying to read the property (in that case 'url') is not defined.

Try use some kind of isset(). In javascript you have a few ways to sort that.

My recommendation for arrays is `myArr[0] !== undefined`, for objects, you can use `hasOwnProperty('url')`. Or just use the short version with `||` :

```
getImageEvent(index: number): object {
    const img = this.events[index].images[0] || {}; // is array defined?
    const imgSrc = img.url || ''; 
    return {'background-image': 'url(' + imgSrc + ')'};
}
```

Read more about [javascript isset() here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281671/3415716)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing in the template using the `?` operator. The `?` operator makes everything after it optional so that you don't get an error trying to read something that is *undefined*.

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url('+events[i].images[0]?.url+')'">
```