# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined demographic.component.html:3

Tags: angular

I am learning angular. Here I am making demographic component as a tag and it is going to use in person component. It shows me error as demographic.component.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined
If any one want to solve it I have uploaded it on stackblitz link is 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uhfoz

person.json

```
{
    "Demographics" : { 
            "ProfileId":1,
            "FirstName":"vinit"
           }

}
```

demographic.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { ScrollPanelModule } from 'primeng/scrollpanel';
import { PersonListService,Person} from './person-list.service';

@Component({ 
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-demographic',
  templateUrl: 'demographic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['demographic.component.css']
})
export class DemographicComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    persons: Person;
    constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
    ngOnInit() {
       // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
       this.getperson();
    }

    getperson(){

      this.personListService.getDemographic()
      .subscribe(
       resp => this.persons = resp.Persons,

        //resp => this.addresses = resp.Addresses,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
 }
}
```

demographic.component.html

```
 <ul>
        <li><b>Demographics</b></li>
        <li>FirstName:{{ persons.FirstName }}</li>
    </ul>
```

person.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jwt from 'angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt';
import { PersonListService} from './person-list.service';

/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded PersonComponent.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-person',
  templateUrl: 'person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['person.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  /*errorMessage: string;

*/
constructor(public personListService:PersonListService){}
  ngOnInit() {
     // console.log(jwt.AuthConfig);
     //this.getperson();
  }


 }
```

person-list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    // import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  // for debugging
    export class Person{

      ProfileId:number;
      FirstName:string="";
    }

    }

    /**
     * This class provides the NameList service with methods to read names and add names.
     */
    @Injectable()
    export class PersonListService {

      /**
       * Creates a new NameListService with the injected HttpClient.
       * @param {HttpClient} http - The injected HttpClient.
       * @constructor
       */
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      /**
       * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
       * @return {string[]} The Observable for the HTTP request.
       */
      getDemographic(): Observable<{Persons: Person}>{
        console.log("Inside the get service")
        return this.http.get('app/person/person.json')

                     // .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                        .catch(this.handleError);

      }
```

person.component.html

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Demographics">

        <sd-demographic></sd-demographic>

    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Comment: I have already answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675500/cannot-read-property-firstname-of-undefined-in-angular/50675554#50675554 Why are you asking the same question again?

Comment: this is different check out the all files here I am importing demographic component to person componet and that solution is not working here

Comment: firstname is not get display can you please tell my mistake

Comment: Your https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uhfoz does not show the same error what you are showing here. Can you fix that first? It has compiler errors too.

Comment: i solved check or tell me where i did wrong