# Jquery datastring var is returning undefined

Tags: jquery, variables

I have searched on SO and couldn't find an appropriate answer.

Very simple. I am defining variables via form submission:

```
var first_name=jQuery("#contact_first_name_1").val();
var last_name=jQuery("#contact_last_name_1").val();
var email=jQuery("#contact_email_1").val();
```

Then defining the "dataString"

```
var dataString =
'first_name='+ first_name + 
'&last_name=' + last_name + 
'&email=' + email +
```

But having a problem if a form field is left empty, it returns "undefined".

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
if (last_name != undefined) {
   '&last_name=' + last_name + 
}
```

I know this is simple, but simply can't get the right code to work on this example.
Thanks!

Comment: What returns `undefined`?

Comment: Can you please try if(typeof obj.year != ‘undefined’) or please add entire code.. also you could always use try catch instead..

Comment: if a "field like contact_last_name"  is left EMPTY when the form submits

Comment: What is `obj` then?

Comment: I guess I can try if(typeof year != ‘undefined’)

Comment: @bestinamir what is catch method ?

Comment: Here’s example of try/catch https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: I'm thinking I need to check if the variable is "issett" first ? Then if it is set, then I can use it..

Comment: I like your thinking here, although it’s PHP function but if you can use it then great else https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281671/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir thanks for this. I updated the code from above. Now it should read pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## !== ''

The value of an empty input is `''` Use ternaries to change the value to `''` when it is `''`.

### Demo

```js
var dataString = '';
var clean = '';

$('#main').on('change', function() {
  var first_name = $('#contact_first_name_1').val();
  var last_name = $("#contact_last_name_1").val();
  var email = $("#contact_email_1").val();
  var mobile = $("#contact_mobile_1").val();

  var first = first_name !== '' ? `&first_name=${first_name}` : '';
  var last = last_name !== '' ? `&last_name=${last_name}` : '';
  var mail = email !== '' ? `&email=${email}` : '';
  var tel = mobile !== '' ? `&mobile=${mobile}` : '';

  dataString = `dataString: ${first}${last}${mail}${tel}`;

  console.log(dataString);
});
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clean = $(this).serialize();
  console.log(`clean: ${clean}`);
  this.submit();
});
```

```html
<form id='main' name='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input id='contact_first_name_1' name='first'>
  <input id='contact_last_name_1' name='last'>
  <input id='contact_email_1' type='email' name='email'>
  <input id='contact_mobile_1' type='tel' name='mobile'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
<iframe src='about:blank' name='response'></iframe>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a better way to declare these variables to see if the variable has any value ? It seems like when any variable = "" or null or undefined, it populates my database as undefined...

Comment: @eberswine That sounds like a database question, unfortunately that is a new question and I'm frontend -- it's out of my scope. If your database gets the string from the demo in my answer it should get only that string not undefined, or null unless you are changing the string again for some reason.

Comment: @eberswine since you are getting this data `onsubmit` use the `required` attribute on the inputs that'll insure that your inputs have a value.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the required attribute is unnecessary. Before it enters the data base, I have it "alert dataString" and the variables are "undefined"

Comment: If you have required the form will not submit until that input has valid data entered by the user. Why are you checking the variables? The data in it's final form is a simple string with no undefined values i.e. `dataString`

Comment: Try `dataString.trim()`

Comment: I wonder if I can have multiple "var dataString =" based on conditions..

Comment: jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "#",
      data: dataString.trim(),

Comment: Sure `var dataString1, dataString2,` etc. or an array

Comment: try  `method: 'POST'`, `type: 'POST'` is pretty old.

Comment: @eberswine I've updated my answer with a live server, `serialize()` and an iframe that shows the response. BTW do you have `name` attribute on your inputs?

Comment: Great ! Yes, I have name attributes on each inputs!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188032/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-eberswine).